# How to Open Web Socket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I'm trying to open a socket -> PHP Page to being in data from, but I'm unsure on how to open it:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://myurl.com/sockets/socket.php");  

if(socket.onopen)
    alert("Open");
else
    alert("Not Open");
```

I have the latest version of jQuery linked in my index (above my link to this script) and there's nothing in my PHP file - it's just to see if I can open the connection. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: WebSockets requires protocol support on the server, specifically support for a HTTP Upgrade handshake with WebSockets security headers.  Simply pointing a WebSocket at a PHP script will not work.

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you mean - so I just need to define what protocol to use to open the script? Do I need something like Node.js? I'm running Apache if it matters.

Comment: Good article on websockets that may clarify some things, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

Comment: @Despertar See that's what I'm using but I figured it linked to a PHP script so I could just do it and start playing around with it. Apparently that's not the case :(

Comment: Also, `socket.onopen` is an *event*, not a boolean.  `socket.onopen=function() { alert('open now'); };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSockets requires protocol support on the server; specifically, support for a HTTP Upgrade handshake with WebSockets security headers. Simply pointing a WebSocket at a PHP script will not work because PHP scripts speak HTTP, and WebSockets are not HTTP – it's an entirely different protocol (albeit one based on HTTP).

If you want to use WebSockets in PHP, you'll need to use a [specialized](http://socketo.me/) [library](https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket) [that implements](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench) the WebSockets protocol (I've used none of these; they're just the first [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websocket)).

Of course, Apache and PHP aren't really the best tool for the realtime job.  I'd use Node (and the excellent [socket.io](http://socket.io) package), which is designed to handle a large number of concurrent, persistent connections.

Comment: Man I must misunderstand entirely what Web Sockets are used for... Though I'm just using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/) which sockets to a PHP script.

Comment: HTTP is a request/response mechanism.  The browser requests a page, and the server (in your case, Apache+PHP) sends a response.  It is impossible for the server to initiate a connection to the browser, or to push data down.  That's where WebSockets come in: the browser leaves a TCP connection open with the server, and the server can send data whenever it likes, not just in response to a request.

Comment: I'd even suggest using nginx over apache (if possible, of course) - from what I understand, each open TCP connection is another apache thread, while nginx helps relieve that (I may be remembering incorrectly the exact problem).